# Deploy .NET web application on AWS using ElasticBeastalk

Tags: iis, web-applications, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application that is to be hosted on AWS using ElasticBeanstalk. There are two options supported for deployment: Web Website or Web Application. In my case, I am trying to deploy a web application on Windows Server environment. I suppose this deployment eventually ends up in IIS within the Windows operating system.

The problem is, "IIS" is not listed as an option when I select "Web Application" on AWS ElasticBeanstalk console. Is this the right approach?

EDIT:

> The description of both is described here:
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a 'New Application' and then a 'New Environment'. When you are creating a new environment, under 'Environment Type' the option is there to select IIS, see screen grab below:

[image]

Comment: George, thanks for that info and screen grab. I indeed saw that it was there for "Web Server", but not for "Web Application". I believe my application falls under a Web Application. It is a .NET application that I need to get hosted on IIS as a "service" and not as a website. And, according to the AWS link, a "web site" serves web requests, while a web application processes background tasks. I believe my .NET service is a "background task", and not a web site per se, no? 
(my EDIT has the link to the AWS description of both types)

Comment: I believe for your requirements Web Server is the choice for you.